# Add wildcard search and else condition

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to add a wildcard character to the search box, but the execution continues even without anything in the search box, how should i stop the search if the box is empty?
Thank you

```
For Each Cognome In intervallo
    If Cognome Like Sheets(1).Ricerca = "" Then
        Exit For
    ElseIf Cognome Like Sheets(1).Ricerca & "*" Then
        Sheets(4).Range(Cognome, Cognome.Offset(0, 8)).Copy
        Sheets(1).Range("A" & (Rows.Count)).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    End If
```

Comment: You can't have two comparisons in the same statement without `and` or `or` Assuming you want to check if `Cognome` is an empty string it would be `If Cognome = ""` then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check for a search term before entering the loop

```vb
Sub MyMacro()

    Dim s As String, r As Long
    Dim Cognome As Range, intervallo As Range

    Set intervallo = Sheets(4).Range("A1:A100")
    r = Sheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    s = Trim(Sheets(1).Ricerca)

    If Len(s) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Search box empty", vbExclamation
    Else
        For Each Cognome In intervallo
            If Cognome.Value2 Like s & "*" Then
                r = r + 1
                Cognome.Resize(1, 8).Copy
                Sheets(1).Range("A" & r).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            End If
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```